# How to remove conda environment from vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I created an environment using conda a long ago, and then I deleted it. But still appears in the VScode kernel list.

[image: rtvc environment]

I already tried `conda env list` but it does not appear there:

```
λ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/vishwa/anaconda3
```

I also tried `jupyter kernelspec list`, but it does not appear there either:

```
λ jupyter kernelspec list 
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/vishwa/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

How can I remove this environment from VScode?

Answer (score 1):

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

or

```
conda env remove --name myenv
```

Comment: From the look of the interpreter path in OP's image, that's not from a conda environment.
This answer worked for me after also restarting vscode.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [full list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) of places where VSCode will try to find your environment. One of these must be the source of your trouble.

Comment: It didn't help. But I just deleted `python` from `usr/bin/python`. Now it's gone.
Note: It also deleted python2.x from my machine (it was not needed so I didn't bother to install it again since I already have python3.)